# Selenium --headless option behaviour?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I`m using Python Selenium to navigate TripAdvisor.com
After running my script for a while, I get banned by IP (or at least it seems that way) 
[image: TripAdvisor ban]
However, when I retry or even run a somewhat similar script from another machine in the same network, the script is still working properly and does not fail due to HTTP 403 or something like that.
I've managed to deduce that *--headless* option for Chrome webdriver has something to do with it. Without it, the script fails as it is supposed to, showing Access Denied as on the screenshot.
So, my question is, what does the webdriver in --headless mod do differently as opposed to not using it?

UPD: I have rephrased the question, as commentors pointed out, nobody has insight into server logic

Comment: You asked the wrong question. Better: "Why does the server not block me in headless mode?". But still not a good question for Stack Overflow since we have no insight into the server logic.

Comment: It will probably you block you even in headless mode but may be it took some time while you run the tests in headless mode and the ip ban was not active anymore. It should work on IP level.